# Search in one column multiple time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

This is my query output :

```
Reg_Id  |  ITSkillName  
----------------------
  118   |  JAVASCRIPT
  371   |  PHP
  371   |  ANDROID
  6170  |  PHP
```

Here, `Reg_Id` is foreign key. I want `Reg_Id` which have PHP and ANDROID skills.

So I have tried like

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.ITSkill AS is2 
WHERE ITSkillName = 'PHP' AND ITSkillName = 'ANDROID'
```

but it returns 0 records. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Think about it... How can a skill name be 'PHP' AND 'ANDROID' at the very same time?! Your current query states "Look through each record and return those where the value of ITSkillName = 'PHP' AND ITSkillName = 'ANDROID'"

Answer (score 3):

You need to `JOIN` the table to itself to get the results you want.

```
 SELECT A.Reg_Id
   FROM dbo.ITSkill A
   INNER JOIN dbo.ITSkill B ON A.Reg_Id = B.Reg_Id AND B.ITSkillName='PHP'
   WHERE A.ITSkillName='ANDROID'
```

---

If you need to match an arbitrary number of skills, but can't guarantee that `Reg_ID, ITSkillName` is unique, you can use a CTE to slightly modify Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer as follows:

```
   ;WITH UniqueSkills AS (SELECT DISTINCT Reg_ID, ITSkillName FROM dbo.ITSkill)
   SELECT Reg_ID,COUNT(*) FROM UniqueSkills AS is2
   WHERE ITSkillName IN(select Skill from @SearchSkills)
   GROUP BY Reg_ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) from @SearchSkills)
```

Comment: Your query gives right output. Actually PHP and ANDROID are parameters and it should be any number of parameters

Comment: @Prashant16 - Then you asked the wrong question <g>. This is why it's important to include all things neccesary to your question but nothing more.

Comment: I could edit my answer, but it'd just end up matching Damien_The_Unbeliever's.

Comment: @Dan - True, you have your answer but take note of the uniqueness warning Damien added. If there ever will be two records with 371|PHP, that solution won't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a relational division problem. If the `Reg_ID` and `ITSkillName` columns, taken together, are unique in this table, then we can just do:

```
   SELECT Reg_ID,COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ITSkill AS is2
   WHERE ITSkillName IN('PHP','ANDROID')
   GROUP BY Reg_ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This generally extends to more skills by adjusting the `IN` clause and the expected count.

I.e. if you have a table-valued parameter containing the skills to search for, you could have:

```
   SELECT Reg_ID,COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ITSkill AS is2
   WHERE ITSkillName IN(select Skill from @SearchSkills)
   GROUP BY Reg_ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) from @SearchSkills)
```

Where `@SearchSkills` is the table-valued parameter.

Comment: You can make `Reg_ID, ITSkillName` unique by doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` in a CTE.

Comment: @Dan - I didn't want to obscure the query too much if the required condition is already met - with no table definition, we don't know whether a `DISTINCT` is required or not, yet. But I did want to make the requirement clear.

Answer (score 3):

Think in sets! What you're looking for is the **intersection** of two sets: those with PHP skills, and those with ANDROID skills. SQL has an `INTERSECT` operator:

```
SELECT Reg_ID FROM dbo.ITSkill
WHERE Skill = 'PHP'

INTERSECT

SELECT Reg_ID FROM dbo.ITSkill
WHERE Skill = 'ANDROID'
```

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: sorry 'bout that :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ITSkill AS is2 
WHERE ITSkillName = 'PHP' 
AND Reg_Id IN( SELECT DISTINCT Reg_Id 
                FROM dbo.ITSkill 
                WHERE ITSkillName = 'ANDROID')
```

**Test**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Reg_Id INT,ITSkillName VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES 
  (118,'JAVASCRIPT'),
  (371,'PHP'),
  (371,'ANDROID'),
  (6170,'PHP')


SELECT * FROM @t AS is2 
WHERE ITSkillName = 'PHP' 
AND Reg_Id IN( SELECT DISTINCT Reg_Id 
                FROM @t 
                WHERE ITSkillName = 'ANDROID')
```

**Result Set**

```
Reg_Id  ITSkillName
371     PHP
```

Answer (score 0):

As marc_s suggested, INTERSECT is a valid alternative. However, depending on how many various Skills there are, it can get kind of heavy since the query optimizer (in my experience at least) may choose less optimal ways to execute the query.

One other option at least, would be to use this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM dbo.ITSkill s
JOIN 
   (SELECT Reg_ID
   FROM dbo.ITSkill AS is2 
   WHERE ITSkillName IN ('PHP','ANDROID')
   GROUP BY Reg_ID
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ITSkillName) = 2) SRC
      ON SRC.Reg_ID = s.Reg_ID
```

Now obviously, you need to update the HAVING COUNT value to match the number of parameters in the IN clause. In code you may sometimes concatenate hundreds of INTERSECT queries, and that's where this model really starts to shine. At minimum it should be around equally effective performance-wise.

**EDIT**: Bah, just noticed damien had the same idea there! But this also has the join to get the results as per the OP so I'll leave it here. Give the creds and fortune to damien. ;)